# trouble install ruby-opencv

Tags: ruby, opencv

I have tried to install ruby-opencv and I can't get it to work.

I am running fedora 15 with rvm using ruby 1.8.7

I have tried this fork as it seems most up to date:
https://github.com/ser1zw/ruby-opencv

I have installed the packages opencv and opencv-devel both of which are version 2.2

When I try to compile the native extensions by running:

```
ruby extconf.rb
```

I get the error:

```
>> check require headers...
checking for core/core_c.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

The mkmf.log file provides this information:

```
have_header: checking for core/core_c.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -E -I. -I/home/derek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -I/usr
/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/opencv2    -g -O2  -fPIC    conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:1:25: fatal error: core/core_c.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include <core/core_c.h>
/* end */
```

does anyone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check where opencv-devel was installed?
This is from the github page:

```
ruby extconf.rb \
  --with-opencv-lib=/opt/local/lib \
  --with-opencv-include=/opt/local/include/opencv2
```

Notice the `-I` lines on your compilation message, they did not include those locations. So double-check where opencv-devel went to, and fix the locations with the `--with-opencv` flags.

Comment: thanks very much - whereis opencv helped me find where it was